# Remove keys from multidimesional array

Tags: php, arrays, array-unset

I have an array name $json_output.

```
array(3) {
  ["ProductsSummary"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["TotalPages"]=>
    int(2)
    ["CurrentPage"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  ["Products"]=>
  array(60) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["LastShopUpdate"]=>
      string(26) "/Date(1382716320000+0200)/"
      ["Score"]=>
      float(0.2208696)
      ["ProductId"]=>
      int(1306413101)
      ["ArticleNumber"]=>
   }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["LastShopUpdate"]=>
      string(26) "/Date(1382716320000+0200)/"
      ["Score"]=>
      float(0.2208696)
      ["ProductId"]=>
      int(1306413101)
      ["ArticleNumber"]=>
   }
```

And so on. I need to unset ProductId and LastShopUpdate from each one.

What i tried:

```
<?php
foreach($json_output["Products"] as $bla)
unset($bla['ArticleNumber'], $bla['LastShopUpdate']);
?>
```

But it is not working. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looping over an array using `foreach`, a copy is usually made. Changing something in the copy of course has no effect on the original. Try this:

```
foreach($json_output["Products"] as & $bla)
    unset($bla['ArticleNumber'], $bla['LastShopUpdate']);
```

The `&` causes `$bla` to be a reference instead of a copy. Therefore it should resolve your problem.